# PHP MYSQL search for postcode using LIKE

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query which searches for postcode using LIKE. Now the postcode is fine if someone puts the full postcode e.g. SW14 4NP. But if someone was to put in SW1 it would return anything with SW1+ results. How can I make it so that if someone put SW1, it would display only SW1 postcode and not SW11, SW14 etc.

My query is:

```
SELECT postcode FROM data WHERE postcode LIKE '$search%'
```

The database for postcodes are stored as SW14 4NP etc with a space.

Comment: Please provide sample table data

Comment: Thanks for the replies, eggyal's answer was better suited as it has more flexibility. I forgot to mention that I have functions in place which validate whether it is a full postcode or an outer postcode. I just couldn't get the query to only show the results based on the outer postcode. Thank you all for the answers as they all do work fine as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [regular expression](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/regexp.html) based pattern matching:

```sql
WHERE postcode RLIKE '^$search( ?[0-9][A-Z]{2})?'
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT postcode FROM data WHERE postcode LIKE '$search %'
```

by simply adding the space after the search key. then it will find all SW1 codes (or whatever you look for) but not the SW11

Comment: Assuming that the data is stored with correctly placed spaces.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  postcode
FROM    data
WHERE   postcode LIKE 'SW1 %'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT postcode FROM data WHERE postcode LIKE '$search %'
```

But say the user inserts only SW, it will return nothing, while with your current query it will return anything starting with SW. Depends what you want to do.