# Php and mysql wildcard operator when searching a database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a list of customer in a database with a column name is postcode

At the moment my search runs the SQL

```
SELECT *
FROM customer
WHERE postcode LIKE '%".$_POST["search term"]."%'
```

Which works fine but if a row in the databse has the postcode of (SS1 1AB) and someone types in (SS11AB) how can I make it find the correct row?

Basically I want to be Able to search every single combination etc

Comment: Before anything else please look into SQL Injection (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).  With your code example above you are wide open for allowing all sorts of nasty things to happen to you data/system when you blindly use data that has not been filtered, cleaned, etc...

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP MYSQL search for postcode using LIKE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16215815/php-mysql-search-for-postcode-using-like)

Answer (score 0):

Only way you could probably do is to with either a regex or white space replacement.

```
PHP: $term = str_replace(' ', '', $_POST["search term"]);

Query: Select * from customer where REPLACE(postcode, ' ', '') LIKE '%".$term."%'
```

Having said that however, you'd be far better off formatting the data on insert, because as your table grows, that lookup will become more and more expensive to run. One of my pet hates is websites that use a post code as authentication or verification data, then force you to use a particular notation. I've seen people hypenate the space in their post code before too, so you should always normalise the format before inserting it, or enforce a format (i prefer the former option, but the latter is easier).

Also your query is vulnerable to injection exploits. But thats another topic

Comment: Only problem is inserting the postcodes with no spaces is we send out invoices and on the invoices it has the customers address and it doesn't look right if the postcode is not formatted correctly

Comment: Unless you have tens of thousands, or even hundreds of thousands, the replace in query will probably be fine, you won't really notice much performance lag, and its going to be the simplest solution right now. At high scale you COULD store a searchable postcode and a display postcode, so you search on one field and output the other to invoices, but that may be a little overkill. If you ONLY ever serve UK customers however, you could format all postcodes with a space with some regex so its always in the "display format", and you can search knowing that fact. But stick with the REPLACE for now

Answer (score 0):

Besides the SQL injection, Which you should sort out.

The column should be SS11AB, then query on `str_replace(" ", "", $_POST['search term'])`

you can make your column look like that by

```
update customer set postcode = replace(postcode, " " , "")
```

That will remove all spaces in the column, Then you just need to query without the space with the function above

Answer (score 0):

Mysql allows regular expression matches which would be one way. What I would do though is standardize on a single correct representation in the database - and validate input against that. This would avoid SQL injection issues and make matching easier. It would also allow you to filter out typos when data is entered into the database.